# ICSP (pickit2) on 3.3v dsPIC33

Tags: pic, 3.3v, pickit, icsp

I'm using a dsPIC33FJ64MC202 (@3.3V) for some project. I normally program my PIC projects with MPLABX through a PICkit 2, but I never tried using it on a 3.3V chip. Will it work?

I know the target Vdd value can be adjusted but, based on the programmer's schematics ([datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51553e.pdf), appendix B, page 77), only the Vdd pin would change and data pins would still be driven by the programmer's internal PIC's outputs (PIC18F2550 @5V).

My PIC's [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/70291f.pdf) says it supports ICSP but it does not clarify if specifically PICkit 2 are supported. The chip has three different PGD/PGC pairs, where two are located on pins that support 5V logic. Is that the only way? Am I supposed to only use those?

Comment: @Dan1138 mine works... It shows up as an alternative tool but it does work... Also: your comment is way off this topic. The fact that I'm using mplabx doesn't affect the question

Comment: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/pickit%202%20readme%20v2-61-00%20(a).txt   lists devices compatible with the PICkit 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you have an official Microchip PICkit 2 or 100% clone it should be able to safely program 3.3V chips. You might want to choose 'manual device select' to ensure that it doesn't apply 5V while trying to detect the device.

Here is part of the schematic showing the ICSP interface. Q2, Q3 and Q5 clamp the signal voltages to target device Vdd if they try to go above it.

[image]

Comment: Kinda off topic but, how does this circuit work?

Comment: The target voltage (VDD_TGT) is present on the anode of D1, (VDD_TGT - Vf of D1) is present on R17, and the base of Q2,Q3 & Q5. When any signal (AUX, ISCPCLK, or ISCPDAT) is greater than (VDD_TGT - Vf of D1) + (Vbe of a Q2/3/5 transistor) then that signal is pulled down through resistors R10,R11 or R14,R15 or R19,R20. The Vf (forward voltage drop) of D1 is about the same as the Vbe threshold of an MMBT3906.